# Creating new "press button" step

Tags: selenium, behat, mink

I need a help to create my own Behat step similar to "When I press ". I'm doing this, because original press method doesn't seem to work correctly.

I want to call it "When I press submit button ..."

So, this is the start of the **FeatureContext.php**'s chunk of code:

```
/**
 * @When /^I press submit button "([^"]*)"$/
 */
public function iPressSubmitButton($arg1)
{

}
```

The question is - what should I write inside these parentheses?

Comment: Why doesn't the existing step definition work?

Comment: @RobSquires, because it doesn't have anything inside braces.

Comment: I mean why are you not using the original step? What errors/unsuitable behaviour are you seeing?